# How to configure 503 (service unavailable) response header in IIS 7 web.config?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, http-headers, web.config

My site is on a shared host and I need to do some maintainance work, which needs downtime.

For SEO reasons I need to cause a 503 http response to be sent to clients.

How can I do that from my web.config file (or any other method?)

Comment: It's possible with a redirect: https://serverfault.com/a/483158/349614

Answer (score 0):

When you use the built-in IIS functionality of the "app_offline.htm" file in the root of the web site, all requests will service that page, and it will return a 503.